# tar: how can I exclude intermediate directories but include leaf directories?

Tags: find, tar

I want to create a tar file suitable for extracting into `/`. I've created a work directory that represents the root of the file system, and it has all the stuff I want included in the tar underneath, like: `etc/rc.d/init.d/glassfish3`, `opt/glassfish3/...`, and other directories and files under `opt/...`.

When I do `tar zcvpf files.tgz *` it includes the intermediate directories (like `etc`, `etc/rc.d`, and `opt`) in the tar file. Then when I extract it into `/` on another system, it has the undesirable behavior of mucking with ownership and permissions on those directories. I really want to leave those alone and not touch them.

So I thought I found a good way around this with:

```
find . -type f -print0 | tar zcvpf files.tgz --null --files-from -
```

which creates a tar that only includes files. This is great, it only gets the files I put in there... except I just discovered it's not picking up important leaf directories, like:

```
opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/asadmin
```

which is an empty directory (and needed by Glassfish3, or it will complain).

**How can I create a tar file that skips intermediates but not final directories?** I have a feeling some find+awk magic might do it. It doesn't need to be a one-liner though, readability is important. Thanks.

---

**Edit**: I found this. Other/better ideas welcome:

```
cat <(find . -type f -print0) <(find . -type d -empty -print0) | tar zcvpf files.tgz --null --files-from -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` can take `-o` for "or", so you can combine your two `find` commands like so:

```
find . \( -type f -o -type d -empty \) -print0 | tar ...
```

Or, if you can guarantee all the files can fit on one command line,

```
find . \( -type f -o -type d -empty \) -exec tar cvfz files.tgz {} +
```