# How can I find all of the directories that contain one or more files?

Tags: find

I have a hierarchy of directories. Some directories do not contain files and they only contain other directories. Some contain files.

For example:

```
- movies
  - 2022
    - action
      - movie.mp4
      - another-movie.mp4
  - 2023
    - drama
      - movie2.mp4
  - 2024
    - thriller
      - movie3.mp4
    - movie4.mp4
```

I want a `find` command that would provide this result:

```
/movies/2022/action
/movies/2023/drama
/movies/2024
/movies/2024/thriller
```

I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544848/zsh-how-to-run-a-script-at-leaf-directories) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58835/tar-how-can-i-exclude-intermediate-directories-but-include-leaf-directories) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463044/recursively-create-empty-files-in-all-empty-leaf-sub-directories), but I could not figure out a `find` command.

**Update**: A directory can have files and directories in it. I updated the question. For example in the `2024` I have a movie and another directory. The result should contain both `/movies/2024` and `/movies/2024/thriller` directories.

Comment: Please make sure to _always_ mention your operating system. Different systems have different implementations of `find` with different capabilities so we need to know what you are working with .

Comment: "Some directories do not contain files and they only contain other directories." – Strictly these must be empty. In Unix/Linux a [directory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_129) is a [file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164) of the type directory.

Answer (score 6):

Find the files of type *regular* and print the enclosing directory. Unique the list to ensure each directory is listed only once. If on a GNU system, that can be done reliably even in the presence of file paths containing newline characters with:

```
find /path -type f -print0 |
    LC_ALL=C sed -z 's!/[^/]*$!!' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
    tr '\0' '\n'
```

Standardly and assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:

```
find /path -type f -print |
    LC_ALL=C sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

Comment: ... or `-printf '%h\0'` to skip the `sed` step (AFAIK a `find` with `-print0` will also support `-printf`).

Comment: May I ask why have you used `-z`? I mean as much as I understand by using `-print0` you remove everything and connect the results together. I tried your code without `-z` and it worked the same. I'm confused about it.

Comment: In general, I would appreciate it if you explain your Regex for `sed` too. Or your entire command in general :D.

Comment: hey @SaeedNeamati, that's a rather broad question. Could you explain what you specifically couldn't figure out?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, basically I didn't get why using `-print0` and removing new lines and then using `-z` flags for all commands. And I didn't understand the `s!` part of the `sed` too.

Comment: as `man find` states, `-print0` uses 0-bytes to separate the search results; `man sed` and `man sort` will tell you that `-z` means "use 0 bytes as the separator". So that was easily solved by reading the official documentation!

Comment: Regarding `s!`: that's just the usual `s` search command in sed, and the delimiter here between pattern, replacement and flags is set to `!`. You have probably seen `s/pattern/replacement/flags`, but the choice of `/` is arbitrary, you can use any character. Here, `!` is used, because `/` is part of the pattern, and having to escape it all the time would be awkward.

Comment: @StephenKitt. No `-print0` is supported my most find implementations these days and will even be in the next version of the POSIX standard. `-printf` AFAIK is GNU-only.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, OK, so “(if your `find` supports GNU-style `-printf`)”.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why the cast to C locale? I don't particularly care about sort order as long as it's self-consistent, and I don't want to truncate multibyte characters that might have a byte corresponding to the character `/`, so what am I missing?

Comment: There is no multibyte character that can contain a `/` character, POSIX guarantees that. `/` (0x2F on ASCII based systems) is the directory separator for the Unix kernel API, and the kernel API has no notion of what character encoding programs in user space may be using.

Comment: As for `LC_ALL=C`, compare the output of `printf '%s\n' $'\x80\x81' $'\xfe\xff'   | sort -u` between the `C` locale and locales using the UTF-8 encoding for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "_sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character_" - is that what you're expecting me to see?

Comment: @ChrisDavies, that's one of the possible outcomes. GNU `sort` doesn't choke but would treat those strings that can't be decoded as text and that are of same length as sorting the same, and therefore only one of them would survive the `-u`. The fairy and vampire characters also happen to sort the same in locales that have those characters on GNU systems as their order is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

```
find movies -type f -print | \
    xargs -r dirname | \
    sort --uniq
```

Read `man find xargs dirname sort`.

Here's an explanation:

- `find` outputs a list of all the files, and their directories, e.g. `/movies/2022/action/movie.mp4 /movies/2022/action/another-movie.mp4 ...` to `STDOUT`.
- `xargs` packs as many filenames as will fit (see `xargs --show-limits </dev/null`), and repeatedly executes `dirname` until `xargs` runs out of filenames.
- `dirname` chops off the righmost `/` and the filename. E.g. `/movies/2022/action/movie.mp4` becomes `/movies/2022/action`and `/movies/2022/action/another-movie.mp4` also becomes `/movies/2022/action/`
- `sort --unique` eliminates duplicate directory names.

This structure (`find`, `xargs`, post-process) is useful for many tasks. Put some effort into understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`find /movies -type d -not -empty -links 2`

To quote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517229/what-does-ls-la-do/517240#517240):

> The number of links is the number of hard links to the file. For a directory, the number of hard links is the number of (immediate) subdirectories plus the parent directory and itself.

So when the number of links is 2, there is only the parent directory (`..`) and itself (`.`), hence no subdirectories.

---

*While this answer worked for the original question, it doesn't work for the later updated question anymore. I'll still leave it, as it might be helpful for others.*

Comment: Can you please explain your command? Especially the `-links 2` on how it makes it possible. Thanks

Comment: @SaeedNeamati [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795686/default-number-of-links-for-directory) is a good summary. `The number of links is the number of hard links to the file. For a directory, the number of hard links is the number of (immediate) subdirectories plus the parent directory and itself.`. So when the number of links is 2, there is only the parent directory and itself, hence no subdirectories.

Comment: Ah I see, using the fact that subdirectories will contain a `..` hardlink. Interesting!

Comment: `-nlinks 2` doesn't work with btrfs file systems. Its directories always have 1 hard link.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDFe['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(ND.Y1)'])
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumnt the `F`ull (non-empty) directories that contain at least `1` file that can be determined to be a regular file (`.`), including `D`ot files (hidden ones).

Replace `.` with `-.` to also take into account symlinks eventually resolving to regular files, or `^/` for files of any type except directory or `-^/` for that check to be done after symlink resolution. Remove the first `D` to not consider hidden directories and/or the second to not consider hidden files in those directories.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of rawhide (rh) (see github.com/raforg/rawhide).

With rawhide (rh) you can do:

```
rh /movies 'd && !empty && "[ -n \"$(rh -ref -- %S)\" ]".sh'
```

`/movies` is a path to search.

The rest is the search criteria:

`d` means it's a directory.

`!empty` means it's not empty. This isn't needed but it makes it faster by reducing the number of shell processes created by the next bit.

`"[ -n \"$(rh -ref -- %S)\" ]".sh` runs the shell command `[ -n "$(rh -ref -- %S)" ]` which checks if there are any regular files in the candidate directory (with a nested use of `rh`).

`rh -ref -- %S` is short for `rh -r -e f -- %S`.

The `-r` is like find's `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to only search one level down.

The `-e f` specifies the search criteria expression `f` which matches regular files.

The `--` stops command line option parsing so as to prevent any malicious filenames from being interpreted as options to `rh` (e.g. `-xreboot`) (thanks Stéphane).

The `%S` is the name of the current candidate directory that the nested `rh` needs to search.

The `[ -n ... ]` tests that the nested `rh` command produced some output (i.e., that it found some regular files in the candidate directory).

Comment: It seems it escapes newlines as `\<newline>` in the expansion of `%S`  which is incorrect for `sh`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use backticks as inside backticks, there's an extra layer of backslash processing. Use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: Using backslash for escaping is not advisable in general. See [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214) for details.

Comment: You're also missing a `--` which is likely introducing ACE vulnerabilities (like if there's a file called `-e"reboot".sh`

Comment: I'd recommend passing the file paths as extra arguments to the shell so they can be referred to as `"$1"` or `"$@"` in the `sh` code (calling sh with `sh`, `-c`, `code supplied by the user`, `sh`, `found-file`), rather than embedding them quoted in the shell code as doing it properly in all contexts is tricky

Comment: Thanks for all the great feedback. I'll follow your suggestion and implement `%s`/`%S` interpolation via extra arguments for `sh -c`. It'll be simpler and correct. And there's no risk of ACE without `--` because there can only be one search criteria (`-e f` in this case). An additional expression (like `-e'"reboot".sh'` would be an error and `rh` wouldn't proceed.

Comment: Still an ACE via a `-xreboot` file for instance. In any case, that `--` is needed.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether backticks or `$(...)` are used. It's only checking that there is some output. It wouldn't matter if some filenames containing backslashes had those backslashes processed (unless I'm missing something). But I never knew there was that difference between backticks and `$(...)`, so many thanks for the new knowledge. I thought `$(...)` was just to make it easier to nest, but it makes sense that not processing backslashes contributes to that. And well-spotted with the `-xreboot`. Thanks.

Comment: Try after `mkdir '\`reboot\`'; touch "$_/f"` where `rh` adds one backslash before the backticks while they should add 3 when that `%S` is expanded inside backticks. But in any case, backslash, backticks, are as valid characters as any in file names, and beware than in some locales, the charset has some characters that *contain* the same byte value as that of those characters (0x5c and 0x60).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to demonstrate and explain the difference. It's much appreciated. Your generosity of time is formidable. I tried this with "echo hi" rather than "reboot" and got the error `sh: 1: echo hi: not found` so it looks like the command can only be a word with no arguments, not that that makes it any less of a problem, but it's interesting/unexpected. I even tried with "reboot" (on a VM) and it refused with `Call to Reboot failed: Interactive authentication required.` Lucky! :-) This will be a good test after reimplementing `%s`/`%S` via extra arguments to `sh -c`.

Comment: That would be because `%S` escapes space with a backslash. You can always replace `\`echo hi\` ` with `\`$X\` ` and pass `X='echo hi'` in the environment (`%S` will likely (hopefully) add a backslash in front of that `$` but inside backticks, `\$` is also special contrary tha `\space`).

Comment: One problem if you change it so the  file name is passed as an extra (data) argument to `sh` (instead of embedding quoted in the code argument) and have the user refer to it as `$1` in the code is that that `$1` invariably needs to be quoted so you'll end up with things like `rh '"whatever \"$1\"".sh'` which will soon ugly and encourage bad practice by omitting the quotes. Maybe you could introduce `{...}` as strong quotes like in TCL (and like in TCL allow them to nest). `rh '{ { blah "$1" | bligh "$2";} }.sh'`.

Comment: GNU `find` has those `-printf '%s %p %m'` which are great (much greater than the equivalent ones in GNU stat for that matters), but lacks the ability to run commands with the expansion of those arguments. What you could do here is have `rh ' {printf "%20d: %s\n" "$RH_SIZE" "$RH_PATH"}.env.sh'` and pass all those as environment variables.

Comment: See also [AT&T's tw](https://github.com/ksh93/ast-open-archive/blob/master/src/cmd/tw/) for a similar project (which never took off unfortunately, and remains quite experimental)

Comment: My intention is to replace `%s` with `"$1"` and replace `%S` with `"$2"`. Will that be OK? It's important that `%s` and `%S` continue to not require additional quoting by the user, and I don't want the user to need to change to using `\"$1\"` and `\"$2\"`. rh also has a `-printf` equivalent/superset (which also doesn't execute). tw! Wow. I think the original version of rh (1990) was inspired by tw presented at Baltimore 89 Usenix. The author knew of it at least. It's barely documented but its language is very powerful. rh's language is very simple.

Comment: I suppose `%s` changed to `"$1"`  could be a problem when used inside single/double quotes or backticks (where `"` in theory needs to be escaped though you can get away without with most modern sh implementations) or heredocs or when preceded with backslash, but I guess it's already a problem atm and at least users would always have the possibility to use `$1` (or `${1%.*}`...) instead of `%s`. Having a `rh '{for file do...; done}.sh.+'` or `rh '{cmd "$@"}.sh.+5'` like  with `find -exec {} +` could be useful as well.

Comment: FYI I've added an entry for your `rawhide` at [How to process JSON with strings containing invalid UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757832)

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work properly if there's a file called `'d && !empty && "[ -n \"$(rh -ref -- %S)\" ]".sh'` in the current working directory. `rh -e 'd && !empty && "[ -n \"$(rh -ref -- %S)\" ]".sh' /movies` seems OK.

Comment: In any case, that's a great tool!  Thanks for reviving and improving it, that's going to be a nice addition to my tool box. Expect me to advertise it here going forward at least wherever the issues mentioned above don't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks. I'll document the ability and possible need to use `$1` or `$2` directly. The `.+` makes more sense with `-x` and `-X` (final actions that could be grouped for speed) rather than with `"cmd".sh` (search criteria for each candidate file) but I'm trying to keep it simple. But I'll probably end up adding it. The desire to make `-e` optional (for streamlined commands) does mean ambiguity, but I think it's worth it, and the heuristic for determining if an argument is a path or an expression seems OK. Thanks for the kind words. I'm really glad you like it. I'm enjoying using it too.